# Grave accent in mysql query with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, escaping

I have an array that contain a grave accent
(exactly this): https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0060/index.htm

I need to use it as a WHERE condition in mysql query.
I need to escape it.
EXAMPLE:

```
$word="D`A";
$result = $pdo->prepare("SELECT COUNT(record) FROM $tablexample WHERE value=:word");
$result->bindParam( ':word', $word );
$result->execute();
echo $result->fetchColumn();
```

Comment: The best part of [prepared statements](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [bindparam](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php)/ [bindvalue](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php) is that you never have to worry about escaping your values to prevent SQL syntax errors.

Comment: @aynber I have updated the question, the result doesn't change! Everytime it return to me 0 as result! NB. in my database there is the same grave accent in the rows

Comment: You should verify your DB contents to contain that exact string first. `SELECT value, HEX(value) FROM …` etc. See also [UTF-8 all the way through](//stackoverflow.com/q/279170)

Comment: @mario That string is definitely present. Are you Italian?

Comment: You're doing the parameter binding correctly. Are you expecting to find rows where value *begins* with 'D\`A' or rows where value is *exactly* 'D\`A'? The `=` comparison operator will only find the latter.

Comment: @BillKarwin the query is certainly correct (as the parameter binding). The query return to me 0 only when it count the string with grave accent!

Comment: Try running the query with the D`A value in phpMyAdmin, does it actually yield the results you're looking for?

Comment: @dearsina SELECT COUNT(record) FROM `example` WHERE value='D`A'
return to me 0. doesn't recognize the accent!

Comment: At this point it doesn't seem like this question is reproducible/answerable for now. A merely visual inspection of the database values does not suffice.

Comment: Try checking for SQL errors, maybe it's something obvious that we are missing. Put the `execute()` method in an `if()` and see if it produces any errors.

Comment: Can you show us the row in your database that has that value?

Comment: There is no mistake! Sure! The problem is only one: how i can search the string that contains the aforementioned accent? you can all test what I'm saying!

Comment: @aynber Sure! https://i.imgur.com/q7vusEm.png (i know D'Angel

Comment: "D'Angel" is **not** the same as "D`A", was that the row you were looking for?

Comment: I'm unable to replicate your error, perhaps you can try it here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dkSnhmb9Eth7ZLRQaiq1cz/0

Comment: That looks like an apostrophe https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0027/index.htm Can you check the output of `select hex(farmacia)` to confirm?

Comment: I'm sorry, current year have a single quote, 2020 have an accent!

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment yet due to reputation, but what you are showing in your screenshot https://i.imgur.com/q7vusEm.png looks like single quote `'`, not an accent.

Or, if it's just how PHPMyAdmin displays accents, you still need to change your query to

```
WHERE value LIKE :word
```

and use

```
$word = '%D`A%'
```

Comment: you are right! the current year have single quote, not an accent. I'm sorry